# Get features of external geojson file

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I'm loading an external geojson file with the next code:

```
var sourceTour2016 = new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'tourdefrance_2016.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  });

  var layerTour2016 = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: sourceTour2016,
      style: styleFunction
  });
  map.addLayer(layerTour2016); // geojson laag toevoegen aan map
```

But how is it possible to have the features in an array? 
if i'm doing

```
features = [];
features.push(sourceTour2016.getFeatures());
```

I receive an empty array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to insert an array into an array, ol.source.Vector().getFeatures() already returns an array, now you could check if your source is ready and then get its features like this :

```
sourceTour2016.on('change', function(evt){
    var source=evt.target;
    if(source.getState() === 'ready'){
       features=sourceTour2016.getFeatures();
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Just if anyone else wants to use your code; you should add a ')' in the end